# Rails custom client side validation message

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using a rails form with client side validations. How can I customize the error message, which current says:

> "Value must be equal to or greater than ... "

Here is the form field:

```
<%= f.number_field :age, placeholder:"Age", class:"form-control", required: true, max:90, min:17, message: 'foo' %>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 API has a way to set [custom error validation message](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Data_form_validation#Customized_error_messages). Look below the example:

Example:

```
<form>
  <label for="mail">I would like you to provide me an e-mail</label>
  <input type="email" id="mail" name="mail">
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

And then adding a JS:

```
var email = document.getElementById("mail");

email.addEventListener("keyup", function (event) {
  if (email.validity.typeMismatch) {
    email.setCustomValidity("I expect an e-mail, darling!");
  } else {
    email.setCustomValidity("");
  }
});
```

Documentation of [`setCustomValidity()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/setCustomValidity).